# Azure Function with HTTP Trigger returns 204 but does not execute function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-triggers

I have a bash script that iterates over all files in a folder and uses `curl` to post them to an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger.

Function details:
 - v2.0 function
 - written in C#
 - consumption plan

Most of the time this works as expected:

- The function executes, putting the file into storage and triggering downstream processes
- `curl` receives a 204 response, which it happily logs
- The function execution is recorded in Kudu, lots of telemetry is recorded in Application Insights

However, on one occasion `curl` has received a 204 *but there is no record of the function having been invoked*; nothing in Kudu and nothing in Application Insights. There is no indication of any error nor or any of the downstream processes being run for that file. A second file, posted ~800ms later, has processed as expected.

There are no significant differences between the files being uploaded: they're both text, from the same source, < 200Kbs in size.

Are there any ideas of what could cause a function to simultaneously appear to trigger whilst not actually being invoked?

Comment: Which plan you are using in your function app?

Comment: It's a consumption plan. I've added that to the question.

Comment: From your description, it works normally most of the time. Is it possible that the function is timeout so it does not trigger? The timeout period of the consumption plan is not specified as 5 minutes, up to 10 minutes.

Comment: I think it's unlikely we're hitting the timeout period. Most executions complete within a few hundred milliseconds so five minutes provides lots of overhead.

I would also expect to see some sort of error reported; currently the trigger appears to be accepted and then the function silently doesn't execute.